# Sqoop import Parquet java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/kitesdk/data/mapreduce/DatasetKeyOutputFormat error

Tags: import, sqoop, parquet

I have cloned sqoop project from [git hub](https://github.com/apache/sqoop) and build it in windows 7 using build.xml using ant to create a sqoop-1.4.6-SNAPSHOT.jar and deployed it in `/usr/lib/sqoop` in cdh5 environment but when I run sqoop import command I get the following error in stack trace :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/kitesdk/data/mapreduce/DatasetKeyOutputFormat
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.DataDrivenImportJob.getOutputFormatClass(DataDrivenImportJob.java:179)
```

Am I doing anything wrong? is using windows for building the project wrong, do I need to add additional jars ?

1. I have deployed all kite sdk jars in sqoop/lib.
2. Added kite sdk to hadoop_classpath.

Comment: Can you describe details of your Windows environment? In Cgywin? And please post the log messages before the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Sqoop manages its dependencies slightly different when cloned than when it's packaged. I highly recommend using [BigTop](http://bigtop.apache.org/) or one of the [distributions](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/downloads.html) of Sqoop instead.

Building on a different operating system than the one you're deploying on should not matter.

In your case, it looks like kite simply isn't being added to your classpath. Since you've built Sqoop manually, you can add the jars to:

> SQOOP_HOME/lib

or

> SQOOP_HOME/build

Next, check your permissions. Make sure that the above directories are accessible by the user running the sqoop command. That user should have execute permissions. Also, the jars should be readable by the user.

If all else fails, reach out to the Sqoop community via the [user mailing list](http://sqoop.apache.org/mail-lists.html).